# How to handle errors inside Custom JsonConverters in asp net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I have used net core 3.1 in my Web API project. To accept the dates in dd-MM-yyyy format from the user in the JSON request body, I have created a DateTime converter, which converts all the incoming as well as outgoing dates to the specified format.

Below is my DateTime Converter:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"));
    }
}
```

And I have registered the same in startup.cs like :

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            //To accept browser headers.
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        }).
        AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        }).
        AddJsonOptions(options =>
         {
             //converter to accept date in particular(dd-MM-yyyy) format
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
         });
```

Now I am facing certain issues in DateTime Converter. I have created an action filter for checking ModelState Errors which gets invoked after an exception is thrown from DateTime converter. Below is the ModelState Error filter:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ApiResponseModel<IEnumerable<ValidationErrorModel>> apiResponseModel = new ApiResponseModel<IEnumerable<ValidationErrorModel>>();

            apiResponseModel.ResponseCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            apiResponseModel.ResponseMessage = string.Join(" ",
                context.ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
                .SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
                .Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
                .ToArray());
            apiResponseModel.ResponseData = null;
            context.Result = new OkObjectResult(apiResponseModel);
        }
    }
```

When the date is not in proper format e.g. in MM-dd-YYYY format, it generates ModelState Error and gives its built-in error message as "The supplied value is invalid".  I wanted to display a different message instead of this built-in message, something like "The {nameofdatetimefield} is not in a proper format.". So how can I achieve the same inside this DateTimeConverter.?

Comment: Are you trying to use `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`? Why do you have a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson` along with a converter that works with `System.Text.Json`? I would try to avoid mixing JSON libraries. Is your `DateTimeConverter` even getting called?

Comment: @ahsonkhan . I have used Newtonsoft.Json because there are certain features that are still not supported in System.Text.Json. And yes DateTimeConverter is getting called.

Answer (score 3):

To address Sunny's issue to ovveride "The supplied value is invalid" message, you have to use throw **JsonException** instead of FormatException.

```
public override DateTime Read(
ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
Type typeToConvert,
JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    reader.GetString(),
    "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out DateTime date))
{
    return date;
}
    throw new JsonException("Property is not in a proper date format.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your converter, instead of using an API like `DateTime.Parse` that throws an exception for input that is in invalid format, you could use the `TryParse` OR `TryParseExact` method and throw the exception yourself with a different error message. I am assuming you still want to keep the type of the exception to be the same (i.e. `FormatException`).

```
public override DateTime Read(
    ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
    Type typeToConvert,
    JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        reader.GetString(),
        "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out DateTime date))
    {
        return date;
    }
    throw new FormatException("A DateTime property is not in a proper format.");
}
```

If you are looking to access the property name itself within a converter (to put in an exception message or for any other reason), **that is not easily doable**. If you really need to, one way to achieve that would be to create a converter for the parent type you are serializing that has the `DateTime` property and access it that way. This approach isn't ideal, especially if you happen to have such `DateTime` properties in many different parent types (as it would require you to create custom converters for all of them). Regardless, here's a snippet as an example using the typical `WeatherForecast` parent type containing a `DateTime` that comes with a `dotnet new webapi` template:

```
// The "Read" side of a JsonConverter<WeatherForecast> implementation

public override WeatherForecast Read(
    ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
    Type typeToConvert,
    JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    var forecast = new WeatherForecast();

    while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
    {
        if (reader.ValueTextEquals(nameof(forecast.Date)))
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
                        reader.GetString(),
                        "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.None, 
                        out DateTime date))
            {
                forecast.Date = date;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatException(
                    $"The {nameof(forecast.Date)} is not in a proper format.");
            }
        }

        // Add logic for creating the rest of the object properties from the JSON.
    }

    return forecast;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your first solution of using DateTime.TryParseExact() and throwing format exception, but as I have an action filter for checking model state errors, it gives the same message. "The supplied value is invalid". I have edited my question for better clarity